# yii beforeFind() как работает

Tags: yii, framework

```
 protected function beforeFind() {
        if(parent::beforeFind())
        {
           switch($this->profile->vid)
           {
               case 1: $this->kto_takoy = 'Заказчик';   break;
                case 2: $this->kto_takoy = 'Исполнитель';   break;
                case 3: $this->kto_takoy = 'Фирма';   break;
           }

            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

это мой beforeFind у меня модельке есть публичное свойство

```
public $kto_takoy;
```

Хочу его инициализировать перед получением с базы
Вобще это нужно что-бы вывести в CGridView в колонке

```
 array(
            'name'=>'kto_takoy',
            'value'=>'$data->kto_takoy',
            'type'=>'html',
        ),
```

Comment: Может лучше в `afterFind()` ?  Боюсь, что $this->profile на данном этапе у вас не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете получать доступ к релейтед-данным, пока вы не получили экземпляр Вашей модели, который вернет `find()`. В случае события `beforeFind()` переменная `$this` содержит экземпляр пустого объекта, как будто вы создали `new ModelName`.
 Соответственно, никаких `profile` быть не может.